# How to determine activity type from health data in flutter application?

Tags: ios, flutter, healthkit

We are working on a Flutter application to display health data in terms of energy burned, steps, walking and running. We are using [health plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/health) to fetch Apple Health data. However we are not able to determine the activity type as whether the activity is walking or running or cycling/biking. We came across something like **HealthWorkoutActivityType** but unfortunately not sure how to filter the data using this enum. We are not getting any activity type in the health data to filter the activity types. Need some quick help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. It is quite possible to fetch the workout type by trying to ask for permission about HealthData Type **"WORKOUT"** and see if the activity type provided in the health data belongs to Cycling, Running or Walking.